# ng-table width and non-overflowing text

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to use the following 3 CSS properties to have my table items appear in one line and display elipses for anything that runs over the allocated width. However, these properties, specifically nowrap, cause the width to be ignored.

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
```

SSCP: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsFuryoOTehNuXblFehN?p=preview
**How can I make it so that I'm able to set the width VIA ng-table?**

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you need a block element. I suggest inside your td you put the content in p tags and put a width on the p tags.

HTML:

```
<td data-title="'Name'" width="310"><p>{{user.name}}</p></td>
```

CSS:

```
td p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:300px;
}
```

Or you can just add a display:block to your td elements, though that might cause other issues.

Comment: I would rather control the width using ng-table, and putting the content in the block element, with the rules on the block element, doesn't achieve this.